# Way to run test.js under server folder when running npm test

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Whenever i run `npm test` and enter 'a' to run all test cases in the application, it with scans only `__tests__` folder under app/src/component. I have a `__tests__` folder under app/server/service which seems do not detect.

Is there a way to configure jest environment to include all `__tests__`folder in the whole project directory (or at least in app/server) to run unit test cases in one run?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) config of Jest allows you to define a regex to detect test files.

> By default it looks for .js, .jsx, .ts and .tsx files inside of **tests** folders, as well as any files with a suffix of .test or .spec (e.g. Component.test.js or Component.spec.js). It will also find files called test.js or spec.js.

It seems that you are overwriting this pattern in your configuration.